# Switching Between Subviews in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subview

So, in an iPhone app I am working on, I've decided that the best way to display all the contents to the user is to have the top part of the screen show some information, and the bottom of the screen show different information.  However, the bottom part will change sometimes, so I was working on implementing that.

Another app that does this is the MTGLife app, here are some pictures:

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/HILMaJPnbLxP6hQRkn_6XA?feat=directlink
  http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/d5wpS8x_aRyAEOBpYYIxwQ?feat=directlink
  http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/RW-BQfqx-VytRim3BxeRZQ?feat=directlink

You see that upon hitting a button, the picker switches over and displays the log.  Hitting the same button switches them back, with a pretty animation.  I would like to do the same thing in my application.  I'm not sure the best way to go about it though...

I was thinking that I would make 2 UIViews, and then would simply flip between them, but I want to get some opinions first on how to do this, and then a push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 UIViews is a good approach. By using the `UIView` animations functions, you can switch between the Log and the Picker with the desired transition.

In the [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application (see `TransitionViewController`), there an example on how to animation two subviews

Comment: Oh my, this is perfect!  Thank you for pointing me to that sample code!